# How can i get 3 Top number from CallLog

Tags: android, calllog

How can I get the top three numbers from `CallLog`, on the basis of the total duration of calls to the number?

For example, given these calls/durations:

- 0123-2323 for 3min
- 0123-2323 for 59min
- 3232-3210 for 15min

The total for `0123-2323` is `totalmin=62`. For `3232-3210` it is `totalmin=15`.

I tried this code:

```
private String getCallDetails(){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Details :");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()){
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "INCOMING";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;
        }
        sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
                + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
    }
    managedCursor.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: What did your code actually produce? What is the problem with it?

Comment: it is displaying all contact i want to display only top 3 contact with

Comment: total_time_for_call=totalCallDuration1Time+totalCallDuration2Time+.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a map and sort it. get your contacts on the basic of call duration and get your top 3 contact like this.

```
 cc1=0;
 Map<String, Integer> sortedMapa = sortByComparator(topsmstreemap, DESC);
 for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedMapDeses.entrySet())
 {
 if(cc1<3) 
 {cc1++;
 }
```